# How do I double SHA-256 the header of block #59,500?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block, hash, sha256

I'm not sure how to combine all of this information.
https://blockchain.info/block/00000000096af43105123c499521e1d131d172e7e1bf2ed0843290a921f1f6a7

Version 
1

Time Bits
470771548 (is this the right number to use for Time Bits?)

Merkle Root
 ff682ef66cd1b56213fd4db9462fb138f6d8c16d706d41969a7eacc819528038

Nonce
16641419

Hash of Current Block 
00000000096af43105123c499521e1d131d172e7e1bf2ed0843290a921f1f6a7

Hash of Previous Block
00000000023bbab0e78a22d27fbd2d0cd13f8302fb3f560138e0e81d087ac7a1

Answer (score 1):

take first 160 symbols from https://blockchain.info/block/00000000096af43105123c499521e1d131d172e7e1bf2ed0843290a921f1f6a7?format=hex

should I explain more? :))))

**update:**

`01000000` version

`a1c77a081de8e03801563ffb02833fd10c2dbd7fd2228ae7b0ba3b0200000000` prev hash

`38805219c8ac7e9a96416d706dc1d8f638b12f46b94dfd1362b5d16cf62e68ff` merkle hash

`27b80a4c` timestamp

`5c670f1c` bits

`8bedfd00` nonce

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I do apologize, I am a still bit confused as to where all of those numbers come from in the link you attached. And why the first 160? Is that in anyway related to RIPE-MD 160? Thanks!

Comment: this is block in hex format. first 160 symbols are block header (80 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you should take the first 80 bytes from the serialized block. Since this data is [hex-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), and each byte takes two hex-digit to encode, a block header is `80 * 2 = 160` digits.
You will notice that a few fields are inverted, it's because they are represented in [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format. Once you double-sha256 this data, you'll find a hash with trailing zeros and not leading, this is also because endianness.

Here is how the mentioned block looks like:
Take the first 160-digits [serialized header](https://mempool.space/api/block/00000000096af43105123c499521e1d131d172e7e1bf2ed0843290a921f1f6a7/header)
`01000000a1c77a081de8e03801563ffb02833fd10c2dbd7fd2228ae7b0ba3b020000000038805219c8ac7e9a96416d706dc1d8f638b12f46b94dfd1362b5d16cf62e68ff27b80a4c5c670f1c8bedfd00`
And parse:
Version: `01000000` (This is 1 in little-endian)
Previous block hash:   `a1c77a081de8e03801563ffb02833fd10c2dbd7fd2228ae7b0ba3b0200000000` (Notice the trailing zeroes)
[Merkle Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree): `38805219c8ac7e9a96416d706dc1d8f638b12f46b94dfd1362b5d16cf62e68ff`
[Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): `27b80a4c`
[Bits](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_is_difficulty_stored_in_blocks.3F): `5c670f1c`
[Nonce](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Nonce): `8bedfd00`

A python 3 code that hashes it:

```
import hashlib
data = bytes.fromhex("01000000a1c77a081de8e03801563ffb02833fd10c2dbd7fd2228ae7b0ba3b020000000038805219c8ac7e9a96416d706dc1d8f638b12f46b94dfd1362b5d16cf62e68ff27b80a4c5c670f1c8bedfd00")
h1 = hashlib.sha256(data).digest()
h2 = hashlib.sha256(h1).digest()
print(h2.hex())
```

It results in `a7f6f121a9903284d02ebfe1e772d131d1e12195493c120531f46a0900000000`, that's precisely the little-endian version of `00000000096af43105123c499521e1d131d172e7e1bf2ed0843290a921f1f6a7`